# Show that the map $G/N → G/H$ defined by $gN → gH$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Inside a proof of Correspondence Theorem, I faced with a claim and I can't prove it:

Question: Suppose that $H$ is normal in $G$ and $N$ is a subgroup of $H$. Then verify that the map $G/N → G/H$ defined by $gN → gH$ is a homomorphism.

Is my answer correct? : since $g_iN=g_iH$ (for $i=1,2$) then $\phi(g_1Ng_2N)=g_1Hg_2H=\phi(g_1H)\phi(g_2H)$.

If not, where is my mistake?

Edit - I add the full text, but note that in the claim in the new paragraph assumptions might be different than previous paragraphs.

[image]

Comment: why is $g_iN=g_iH$? Is $N$ just a subgroup of $H$ or a normal subgroup of $H$?

Comment: still doesn't make sense. Moreover without $N$ being normal in $G$, how can you define the quotient group $G/N$?

Comment: @AnuragA: "defined by gN→gH"? Just a subgroup of H. What if it would be a normal subgroup of H, then $g_iN=g_iH$ is correct?

Comment: still it won't be correct.

Comment: ^ I have to agree tih @AnuragA. even if $N$ is normal in $H$, we can't say that $N$ is normal in $G$, therefore we can't assume that $G/N$ is even a group. Im guessing there is missing information.

Comment: @AnuragA: I add the full proof of the theorem to my OP. The claim without proof (i.e. my OP) doesn't say if N is normal in H or G (separate claim) though it was considered to be normal in H but in opposite H was not normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more precise I would consider also the multiplication of the equivalence classes in the following way: $ \phi(g_1Ng_2N)= \phi(g_1 g_2 N) = g_1 g_2 H=g_1Hg_2H=\phi(g_1N) \phi(g_2N)$ I used the fact that H and N are in fact the identities of the equivalence classes (cosets)

Comment: N is not normal in G by assumption.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I have used just the definition of the cosets multiplication

Comment: @Salvatore this coset multiplication is well-defined only for normal subgroups.